# Actionscript -> Any article about the difference between getLayoutBoundsHeight and getPreferedBoundsHeight

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript

Can't find any article about the difference . Does somebody know one?

Answer (score 0):

[getLayoutBoundsHeight](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/core/ILayoutElement.html#getLayoutBoundsHeight%28%29) will do this:

> Returns the element's layout height. This is the size that the element
>   uses to draw on screen.

[getPreferredBoundsHeight](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/core/ILayoutElement.html#getPreferredBoundsHeight%28%29) will do this:

> Returns the element's preferred height.

In the context of Flex, the size of a component is always determined by its' parent.  A component cannot size itself.  A measure() method must be implemented--it is part of the component lifeCycle--and it will set the measuredHeight (and measuredWidth) of a component.  So, the layoutBoundsHeight is the actual height.  The preferredBoundsHeight is the desired height.  In Flex, especially when dealing with layout containers or percentage layouts, Flex may make decisions to size a component differently than the measured size.